# Class-wide Event is Malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, class, events, mouseenter

I create a 16x16 grid of `divs` in JavaScript.
Each `div` has a `mouse enter` event (inherited based on **common class**) that should change its **black** background to **white**.

**Here's my problem:** whereas each `div` should change color when it's hovered over, all `divs` (when hovered over) cause the same bottom-right `div` to change color, rather than themselves.

---

I believe all of the events reference the final div under the className "squares" (bottom right div). **How do I make each event reference its own div?**

**SNAPSHOT**
[image]

**CODE**

```
    //GRID CREATION (30x30)
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var size = 30;

    //Row Creation (30)
    for(j=0; j < size; j++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.classList.add("row");

        //Square Creation (30 per Row)
        for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
            var square = document.createElement('div')
            square.classList.add("square");

            //div background-color changes on mouse-enter   
            square.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => { 
                this.square.style.background = 'white';
            });

            row.appendChild(square);
        }
        container.append(row);
    }
```

Comment: What’s `this.square`?

Comment: You need to create a closure, because `this` is applying to the final iteration of the loop. Create a function, pass in `this` and change the background there

Comment: @SterlingArcher: `this` is the same across all of the loop iterations though

Comment: @Ry︁ right, but assuming `this` is a class reference, even removing `this`, wouldn't it be bound outside of the loop?

Comment: @Ry @SterlingArcher I originally did not have `this` and the same problem existed: all events affected the bottom-right div only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s strange to find `this.square` in your event listener when nothing else refers to `this.square`. Perhaps you originally tried `square.style.background`, which didn’t work for the reason described in [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), then tried to fix it with `this.style.background = 'white';`, which didn’t work because it was an arrow function, then tried to make `this.square` work…?

Anyway, use either a non-arrow function, to get `this` inside to be the element the event listener was attached to instead of the same as the `this` outside:

```
square.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () { 
    this.style.background = 'white';
});
```

or better, declare your variables with `let` – which must be available, since you were using an arrow function – and refer to `square`:

```
//GRID CREATION (30x30)
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let size = 30;

//Row Creation (30)
for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    row.classList.add("row");

    //Square Creation (30 per Row)
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let square = document.createElement('div');
        square.classList.add("square");

        //div background-color changes on mouse-enter   
        square.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => { 
            square.style.background = 'white';
        });

        row.appendChild(square);
    }
    container.append(row);
}
```

Declarations for `j` and `i` were missing, too. You should enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and never use `var` to avoid these types of problems.